# Screen resolution issue after installing new graphics driver — Toshiba notebook (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, resolution, display-driver

My device is a Toshiba Satellite Pro C650 (model number PSC09A-01V021), running Windows 10 Home. The system type is 32-bit OS, x64-based processor. The processor is a Celeron(R) Dual-Core CPU (T3500 @ 2.10GHz), with 2 GB RAM. The default refresh rate is 75 (possibly 64?) Hz.

I had been using the default graphics driver for years, however, I recently tried to update it in order to make more games accessible from my notebook.

I installed an Intel Display Driver (2016  version) from the Dynabook website after searching for my specific model. Following this, my display resolution changed from the default of 1366x768 to 1024x768, leading to a ‘stretched’ appearance for text/applications. (In Settings, I am currently able only to switch between two options, the new resolution and 800x600.)

The option to “rollback driver” in monitor properties is greyed out. Uninstalling the Generic PnP Monitor changes nothing. I have even tried forcing a display resolution change using the third-party Custom Resolution Utility, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions for returning my screen resolution to 1366x768, and potentially reverting any other hidden changes?

EDIT: My most recent step has been trying to install generic Intel graphics drivers, however, all of these have superior system requirements. (The Intel website does not offer drivers for my particular processor.)

Comment: Try Intel themselves - https://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx?  - but note the GPU in that machine doesn't have any 'proper' drivers for Win 10.

Comment: Indeed, only two unrelated ‘diagnostic tools’ are offered. Thanks for the suggestion though :) @Tetsujin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Device Manager -> Display adapters, there were two identical drivers listed. I uninstalled the one that only had recent hardware changes/events recorded. After restarting my notebook, the native resolution had returned, and my device ran a lot smoother! The default graphics driver now appears under ‘Display adapters’.